# Order list of objects by property of nested object with NHibernate 1

Tags: nhibernate, object, properties, nested

I have an object with a nested object and want to order a list of objects by a property of the nested object. As I have to, I use an old NHibernate version (1.0 or something).

```
public class MyObject
{
  public NestedObject
  { Get; Set; }
}

public class NestedObject
{
  public string Name
  { Get; Set; }
}

public List<MyObject> GetOrderedByNameOfNestedObject()
    {
        ISession session = SessionProvider.GetCurrentSession();

        List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();

        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MyObject));

        criteria.AddOrder(new NHibernate.Expression.Order("NestedObject.Name", true));

        ..

        return objects;
    }
```

I get the error

```
could not resolve property:NestedObject.Name of :MyObject
```

I am pretty sure this is possible in newer NHibernate versions but don´t know wether in old ones too. I can get around this with HQL but would like to avoid it.

**UPDATE**

I too tried to insert

```
criteria.CreateAlias("NestedObject", "n");
criteria.AddOrder(new NHibernate.Expression.Order("n.Name", true));
```

with no success.

My NHibernate version is 1.0.2.

**Stack Trace**

at NHibernate.Persister.AbstractPropertyMapping.ToColumns(String alias, String propertyName)
   at NHibernate.Expression.AbstractCriterion.GetColumns(ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, Type persistentClass, String property, String alias, IDictionary aliasClasses)
   at NHibernate.Expression.Order.ToSqlString(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Type persistentClass, String alias)
   at NHibernate.Loader.CriteriaLoader..ctor(IOuterJoinLoadable persister, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory, CriteriaImpl criteria)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Find(CriteriaImpl criteria)
   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List()
   at DirectLink.Persistence.Repositories.ProcessRepository.GetAllByReportingTimeIdKeyFigureTypeGroup(Int32 reportingTimeId, String keyFigureTypeGroup, String orderCategory, Boolean ascending) in C:\Users\jan-frederik.carl\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\HRE\DirectLink\Persistence\Repositories\ProcessRepository.cs:line 62
   at DirectLink.Applications.Summit.Summit_Interface2.EntriesGrid_Sorting(Object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) in C:\Users\jan-frederik.carl\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\HRE\DirectLink\DirectLink_Web\Applications\Summit\Summit_Interface2.aspx.cs:line 131
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnSorting(GridViewSortEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSort(String sortExpression)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Can you provide the exact NHibernate version and a stack trace of the exception? I have Nhibernate 1.0.2 source handy and it seems that this exception should not happen there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CreateAlias` to access associations.

[The docs](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-associations) can't hurt.